# ip tables portforwarding what happens on MASQUERADE?

Tags: iptables

I have the following setup:

Client:

- DCHP 192.168.1.*

Raspbian gateway:

- 192.168.1.20

Raspbian server:

- 192.168.1.19

The server is hosting a live camera feed on port 8000.

I want to access this live feed through my gateway, and I want to achieve that using iptables.

I added the following rule:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.19
```

When I access navigate to 192.168.1.20:8000 I am getting a connection timed out. After reading a bit I understand that I need to make another rule that deals with the reply. That can be done using SNAT or MASQUARADE.

I don't want to hardcode a return address, since the "clients" can have different IP addresses. But how can I tell iptables to "remember" the source IP address that was provided in the tcp request, and put that back as "return to sender" address in the reply?

I just tried:

```
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

It works, but I have no idea what I am doing now. What is the MASQUERADE doing?